# SVN: library folders outside project tree - can this be handled with externals

Tags: svn

I could not figure out an answer to a Question I am fighting with:
Coding with LabVIEW, my projects are in a local tree like C:\projects\Thisproject...
The libraries, however are (must be?) subfolders of labVIEW, like ...\LabVIEW\user.lib\mydriver...
I would like to, for a given version of Thisproject, also have checked out the respective versions for the libraries. I thought of externals, but the examples I have seen so far only showed relative pathes to the project path. 
Can anyone proove that and/or give me a hint on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

External URLs can point to any valid SVN url, doesn't have to be relative at all.

Comment: Sorry - Q was meant the other direction. Not the SVN-url, but the target(s) are not direct subdirs, but quite different pathes

Comment: @Lul, I don't understand your question, don't you want to checkout the libraries when you are checking out your project source? And those libraries are somewhere in SVN, right?

Comment: Right! But the compiler expects libraries to be generic and at a position relative to it, not to the project tree.

Comment: @Lul, ah! This seems to be a setup problem instead, fix your Makefiles :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the SVN checkout under the LabVIEW folder and work from there. Why does your SVN working copy have to be in `c:\projects`?

Comment: It does not 'have to be', but always was outside of the LabVIEW tree. NI, the LabVIEW-maker, always warned for storing private stuff inside their folders (except user-libs), but when having my stuff under version control I could easily repair any damage, a NI-update etc. could have done. Thx for that idea!

Answer (score 0):

The pathes show that you are using windows. Therefore you may solve this problem by using directory links. Put the libraries inside your SVN repository and then create a symbolic link to the directory "mydriver" in your repository holding your libraries:

```
mklink /D C:\projects\Thisproject\mydriver C:\LabVIEW\user.lib\mydriver
```

This creates a linked directory C:\LabVIEW\user.lib\mydriver which is part of your SVN working copy and therefore automatically updated if you update your project.

Note: Mklink is a tools shipped with Windows Vista and newer. If you are on WIndows XP there are similar freeware tools which can create symbolic directory links.